# Eclipse WindowBuilder Pro - Exportar Projeto

Tags: java, eclipse

Estou tendo dificuldades em exportar o meu projeto com ícones.

1º Exportar -> "Runnable jar file"
2º Deixo marcado a primeira opção.
3º Quando rodo no Linux ou em outra máquina que não seja a minha os ícones não são exibidos de modo algum.

Uma das label está assim:

```
lblIcone.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
   ".\\- Projetos\\Pizzaria\\src\\Icones\\ecommerce-and-business-icons\\128\\company.png"));
```

Alguém poderia me orientar como resolver isso?

Comment: Se você copiar suas imagens e colocar junto do seu .jar exportado funcionará. Isso resolve para você ou voce precisa que as imagens vão dentro do seu jar?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido:

1º Criar um "folder" dentro do "src" e depois só arrasta os icones/images dentro do "folder" e alterar o código abaixo:

Para label, button etc.

```
btSair.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/deskclin/resources/sair_menu.png")));
```