# Como compilar Java com ícones

Tags: java

Anteriormente, [postei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20568/eclipse-windowbuilder-pro-exportar-projeto) uma dúvida de como compilar meu projeto em "Runnable Jar" com ícones.
E conseguir fazer isso com label e buttons. Agora minha dúvida é como fazer isso em `iconImage`. Tentei o seguinte:

```
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("D:\\Utilitários\\Desenvolvimento\\Eclipse JEE Kepler SR2 (x64)\\- Projetos\\Pizzaria\\src\\Icones\\fatcow-hosting-extra-icons-2\\16\\pizza.png"));
```

Porém não funcionou, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Sua imagens deve esta em uma pasta do pacote de fontes exe.: src/images/img.png
2. Seguindo o passo 1, quando gerar o .jar da app não vai precisar de pasta externa;
3. Segue código:

   ```
   URL imageURL = getClass().getResource("/images/confirmar.png");
   ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
   frame.setIconImage(imageIcon.getImage());
   ```

Espero que lhe ajude.